# Try 'sentinel register --help' for help. Error: No such option: -c

Tags: jaseci

I ran the bellow code in the Jaseci shell which can find here. (https://docs.jaseci.org/docs/tutorials/quickstart/#visualizing-a-graph)

[Example code from the tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUn15.png)

But, I got the bellow error.
[Error after compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6M6B.png)

According to the tutorial, expected output should be like this.
[expected outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDKsN.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular tutorial you are using appears to have been created with an older version of Jaseci, the command should be
`sentinel register -name fam -set_active true fam.jac`

The code parameter is simply an argument and not an option that needs a `-code` before it.

Comment: indeed, you could also simply do `sentinel register fam.jac` and things should just work as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the answer. Would you mind can you send me the latest version of the documentation?